# Using more than one filter in CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, silverlight

On my code i have itemsControl and i want to filter the items that are pressent.

SO, I define CollectionViewSource and i wrote this code :

```
        CollectionViewSource view = new CollectionViewSource();
        view.Source = myItemCollection;
        view.Filter += ( s, e ) =>
        {
            e.Accepted = ( ( myItem )e.Item ).FilterFiels.Equals( stringFilter );
        };

        itemsControl.SetBinding( ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source  = view
        } );
```

Now, I want to use more than one filter in my code. 
That mean that i want to use filter    stringFilter_1 and stringFilter_2

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compound your filter expression with appropriate conditional operators (i.e. && and ||)

Comment: Just unsubscribe the event handler as normal. This might be quite useful - http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=32

Comment: In case the number of the filter is unknown ?